# Backpropagation from scratch -- having trouble with some matrix multiplications

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

I'm trying to implement a neural network from scratch and I'm having trouble correctly implementing the backpropagation. I feel like I'm either calling the wrong indexes of a weight/activation or I'm just not implementing the matrix multiplication correctly. I can't get the matrixes to align properly.

Please note cost is sum of squared errors. I'm taking the gradient of cost with respect to Z.

Instead of posting the entire code, I will just post the relevant parts.

My networks are :

```
#[3,5,5,1] 3 inputs, 5 hidden units, 5 hidden units, 1 output unit

##a[-1] = [1,1]
##a[-2] =[1,5]
##a[-3]= [1,5]
##a[-4]= [1,3] #input layer

weight shapes as follows :

##weights[-1] = 5,1
##weights [-2] = 5,5
##weights [-3] = 3,5 #first layer

Zs:

##zs shape: (1, 1) [-1] #last layer z
##zs shape: (1, 5) [-2]
##zs shape: (1, 5) [-3] #first layer z

  #code for generating data
  def psuedo_training_data():
    input_data = np.random.randint(1, 5, (500,1,3))
    labels =np.random.randint(0,2,(500,1))
    training_data = [(x,y) for x,y in zip
                     (input_data[:int(len(input_data)*.8)], 
                            labels[:int(len(labels)*.8)])]
    testing_data = [(x,y) for x,y in zip
                     (input_data[int(len(input_data)*.8):], 
                            labels[int(len(labels)*.8):])]
    return  training_data, testing_data



 def sigmoid_derivative(z):

        return sigmoid(z) * (1-sigmoid(z))

 def sigmoid(z):
       return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))



def calculate_gradients(weights, biases, x, y):


    weight_derivatives, bias_derivatives, activations, zs =  gather_backprop_data(weights, biases, x,y)
#weight derivatives and bias_derivatives are empty shells

 #gradient of cost with respect to  Z of last layer
    last_layer_z_error = (activations[-1] - y) * sigmoid_derivative(zs[-1])


    #updating the weight_derivatives of final layer
    weight_derivatives[-1] =  last_layer_z_error * (activations[-2]).T
    bias_derivatives[-1] = last_layer_z_error


   #attempting to get the gradients of the hidden layers 

    z_previous_layer = last_layer_z_error
    for i in reversed(range(1,len(weights))):
        print('layer:', i)
        print('****************************************')
        print('z_previous_layer.shape', z_previous_layer.shape)
        print('weights[i-1].shape', weights[i-1].shape)
        print(' sigmoid_derivative(zs[i-1])',sigmoid_derivative(zs[i-1]).shape)
        print('******************************************************')

        z_previous_layer =np.dot(weights[i].T, z_previous_layer)*
 (sigmoid_derivative(zs[i-1]))



        print('********************************************')
        print('activations i -1', activations[i-1].shape)
        print('z_previous_layer_post.shape', z_previous_layer.shape)


        weight_derivatives[i-1] = np.dot(z_previous_layer,activations[i-1].T)
        bias_derivatives[i-1] = z_previous_layer


    return weight_derivatives, bias_derivatives 



FSE:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-399-ee974769393b> in <module>()
----> 1 stochastic_gradient_decent(training_data,testing_data, 5, 25, NN.weights, NN.biases, NN)

<ipython-input-395-e78e37a1fda0> in stochastic_gradient_decent(training_data, testing_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, weights, biases, neural_network)
     13         for mini_batch in mini_batches:
     14             for x,y in mini_batch:
---> 15                 weight_derivatives, bias_derivatives = calculate_gradients(weights, biases, x,y )
     16 
     17                 for i in range(len(weights)):

<ipython-input-393-bb458045ab42> in calculate_gradients(weights, biases, x, y)
     19         print('******************************************************')
     20 
---> 21         z_previous_layer =np.dot(weights[i].T, z_previous_layer)*(sigmoid_derivative(zs[i-1]))
     22 
     23 

ValueError: shapes (1,5) and (1,1) not aligned: 5 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Comment: This might be related to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560298/python-numpy-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes

Comment: What is the line that causes the `ValueError`?  Also, what does `zs` look like?

Comment: @andrew_reece  `Zs` are the same shape as the activations sans the first activation which is the input values. 

`weight_derivatives[i-1] = z_previous_layer * activations[i-1]` -- This line is causing the error.

Comment: @ihpar   Thanks. I'm hoping someone who has implemented NN from scratch would be able to chime in because I feel like I could probably manipulate the numbers with dot products or broadcasting.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can post a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including sample data (not just commented examples) and the `sigmoid()` function you use in `sigmoid_derivatives()`.  It doesn't really seem like a backprop-specific issue you're having, just normal linear algebra bugs.  With a working example it should be easy to sort out.