# Getting value error while performing numpy.dot()

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, valueerror, dot-product

I created two arrays using numpy:

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([[1, 5, 7], [6, 8, 9]])
b = np.array([[1, 8, 8], [5, 8, 0], [8, 9, 0]])
np.dot(a, b)
```

Now, while performing `np.dot(a, b)` I am getting the error :

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (3,3) .

Normally, value error is raised if the last dimension of a is not the same size as the second-to-last dimension of b. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Your code runs for me

Comment: @MeghaliAgrawal You are correct. I wonder if there are version differences...Which one are you using?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am using python version 2.7. It worked with python version 3. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: And NumPy version?

Comment: @MeghaliAgrawal please tell what do you get when you do `np.matmul(a, b)` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. numpy version is - 1.14.0

Comment: @kmario23 [[ 82 111   8]
 [118 193  48]
 [ 53 136  64]]

Comment: Works fine for me on Python 2.7.14 and NumPy 1.14.0. @MeghaliAgrawal: How did you install NumPy?

Comment: @MarkDickinson installed numpy using the command : pip install numpy

Comment: I just wonder... Are you sure you are running this exact code?

Comment: @MeghaliAgrawal how come you get different result for `matrix multiplication` ? ;) Please check your array inputs. Are you sure that you're running the code that you posted?

Comment: @kmario23 running the exact same code
>>> import numpy as np    
>>> a = np.array([[1, 5, 7], [6, 8, 9]])
>>> b = np.array([[1, 8, 8], [5, 8, 0], [8, 9, 0]])
>>> np.dot(a, b)

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, I am running the exact same code.

Comment: Something is fishy here... This is that rare case where a screenshot would be needed to convince...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am sorry. I don't know how to add images in comments. If you could help me with it, I will paste the screenshot.

Comment: @MeghaliAgrawal You usually [edit] the question itself to make clarifications.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think I got what OP was doing wrong. It was due to using `*` operator for matrix multiplication. Now, I indeed get the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (3,3) `

Comment: @kmario23 Yes, I saw such a question here on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560298/python-numpy-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes)). But the OP is claiming otherwise....Anyway, since no clarification is coming, VTC as non-reproducible.

Comment: `np.dot` does not use broadcasting, so shouldn't give this error.  That makes me suspect that `np.dot` has been redefined by the users own code, or some module that has been imported.

Comment: @MeghaliAgrawal [Please consider accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it has helped else please let me know the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Your code works fine. Please note that when the inputs to [`np.dot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) are matrices, [`np.dot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) performs **matrix multiplication**

```
In [18]: a = np.array([[1, 5, 7], [6, 8, 9]])
    ...: b = np.array([[1, 8, 8], [5, 8, 0], [8, 9, 0]])
    ...: 

# @ is equivalent to `np.dot()` and `np.matmul()` in Python 3.5 and above
In [19]: a @ b
Out[19]: 
array([[ 82, 111,   8],
       [118, 193,  48]])


In [20]: (a @ b).shape
Out[20]: (2, 3)

# sanity check!
In [22]: a @ b == np.matmul(a, b)
Out[22]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

---

Note on `@`: It was introduced in Python 3.5 as a [dedicated infix operator for matrix multiplication](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)

This is because some confusion existed whether `*` operator does matrix multiplication or element-wise multiplication. So, to eliminate confusion, a dedicated operator `@` was designated for matrix multiplication. So,

**`*`** performs *element-wise multiplication*
**`@`** performs *matrix multiplication* (dot product)

---

Comment: The easiest way to perform a hassle-free dot product with two-dimensional NumPy arrays `a` and `b` is `(a * b).sum(axis=-1)`