# How do I change the shape of data file that I extracted in Python? (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, jupyter-notebook, shapes

I'm using mapped earth data and was able to subtract monthly data (e.g. Relative Humidity) from model and observational data. I want to subtract observational data from the model data to see the difference between the two.

When I try taking away the observation data from the model data I get: "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (197,258) (18,36)"`.

Someone suggested that I regrid the data but I'm not sure how to do that. I tried using `scipy.interpolate` but I'm unsure what function would work best for my situation here.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560298/python-numpy-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes

Comment: Thanks. But from this comment, I think I need to look into regridding the shapes of the data.