# unable to multiple two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

While running this code, getting the value error:

```
mask_image_temp = np.zeros((1080,1920), dtype=np.uint8)

ndarray_blue = np.array([[1100,600], [375,600], [520,400], [960,400]], np.int32)

polygon_blue = cv2.fillPoly(mask_image_temp,[ndarray_blue],color=1)

polygon_blue = polygon_blue[:,:,np.newaxis]

polygon_blue = cv2.resize(polygon_blue,(960,540))

blue_color_plate = [255,0,0]

blue_image = np.array(polygon_blue * blue_color_plate,np.uint8)
```

[image]ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (540,960) (3,)

**Expecting these results:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python numpy ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560298/python-numpy-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes)

Comment: @Henry i have tried reshaping also but iam doing something wrong there also, can u please tell me using above code

Comment: I don't know how to fix that, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got the solution** ,it may be due to resizing polygon_blue before multiplication with blue_color_plate .

**Solution**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, I deduce that in:

```
polygon_blue * blue_color_plate
```

the first is (540,960) shape, and the second, (3,)

The second is (by the previously line), with an obvious shape of 3:

```
blue_color_plate = [255,0,0]
```

and the other from the previous `csv.resize` line

As to correction, we don't know the author's intention, so can't suggest a fix.

Comment: iam working on yolov5 deepsort counting ,where if object crosses the line,it should be counted.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the big picture.  I don't know the purpose of the problem multiplication.