# ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm multiplying two matrix of shape (3,2,2,2) and shape (2,2,2,2) which as far as I understand should multiply correctly.

```
np.random.randn(3,2,2,2)@np.random.randn(2,2,2,2)
```

Raises the error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,2,2,2)->(3,2,newaxis,newaxis) (2,2,2,2)->(2,2,newaxis,newaxis)  and requested shape (2,2)
```

Seeing it in the context of 3x2 and 2x2 matrix with each element as 2x2, the matrix multiplication should work correctly, but doesn't. Looking for correction here.

Edit: using `np.dot(np.random.randn(3,2,2,2),np.random.randn(2,2,2,2))`
does result in a valid multiplication however, the resultant shape is `(3,2,2,2,2,2)` which is not expected. Following conventional rules the output shape should be `(3,2,2,2)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python numpy ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560298/python-numpy-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes)

Comment: What shape do you want the result to be?  `matmul/@` pairs the last 2 dimensions in the conventional matrix multiplication way - last dim of A with the 2nd to the last of B.  Since they are both 2, that part's ok.  But it uses `numpy broadcasting` rules for the first 2 dimensions.  (3,2) does not broadcast with (2,2).

Comment: @hpaulj I'd expect the shape of the result to be ```(3,2,2,2)``` given conventional matrix rules. Note that np.dot does give me a valid result of shape ```(3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)``` which is not expected. I see that you're explaining just that but I don't think I understand it yet.

Comment: Have you read the `np.matmul` docs?  `np.dot` handles the larger dimensions different.  It still does the sum-of-products with 'last-2nd to last rule'.  You may want to demonstrate the calculation with loops, or with `np.einsum`.

Comment: Matrix multiplication performs a `sum-of-products` on one pair of dimensions.  For 2d arrays, you (manually) run your finger across the columns of one array while going down the rows of the other, a (3,2) can multiply a (2,4) to produce a (3,4).  `dot` and `matmul` extend that 2d to higher dimensions, but with different rules.  `dot` in effect does an `outer` product, while `matmul` uses `broadcasting` rules.

Comment: Both `matmul` and `dot` are doing `np.dot(A[i,j,:,:], B[k,l,:,:]), but with different ways of mixing the `i,j,k,l` dimensions.  The `dot/matrix product` is done on the last 2 dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj np.matmul performs np.dot under the hood as far as I remember which seems to be precise when I do matmul of the two matrices instead. It seems using np.einsum to do the matrix operation is the only way. Edit: You're correct, matmul uses broadcasting rules instead. So I could iterate through the dimensions to perform the intended multiplication instead?

Comment: There are no "conventional rules" for matrix multiplication involving 4d arrays.  MATLAB doesn't allow that.  `numpy` has extended the conventions, but you have to either follow its rules, or be explicit about what you want done.